# Обводка вокруг формы

Tags: форма

В заголовке главный вопрос.
Сделал я форму поиска, но при нажатии на нее появляется синяя обводка. И вот, главный вопрос: **Как ее убрать?**

Форма на сайте - [bifot.ru/cloud/search/index.html](http://bifot.ru/cloud/search/index.html)

**Скрин, чтобы понять лучше** - http://bifot.ru/cloud/search.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта рамка убирается установкой CSS свойства `outline`:

```
.form-search input {
    outline: 0;
}
```

http://htmlbook.ru/css/outline

Comment: оно убирает и начальную обводку.

Comment: мне надо обводку оставить, а при active убрать.

Comment: @bifot Магия! Магия!

    .form-search input:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

Comment: так бы сразу, большое спасибо.

Comment: @bifot а вот никто ваши мозги не отрицает, могли и сами подогнать