# border у тега select либо option

Tags: html, css

```html
<SELECT>
<OPTION>ул.</OPTION>
<OPTION>пер.</OPTION>
<OPTION>шоссе</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Подскажите уважаемые специалисты, как убрать при hover,focus рамку которая появляется , прошу заметить что варианты как:

```
select:focus,
select:hover,
option:hover,
option:focus {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  border:transparent;
}
```

не работает в большинстве броузеров ! Прошу помочь

Comment: вендорные префиксы должны помочь

Comment: например ! покажите код

Comment: Вот пример:
-moz-border:none; // для фаерфокса
-webkit-border:none; // для хрома

Comment: вы реально проверили это ? у меня не работает во сех браузерах - и с webkit на chome на ретина safari на linux не работает во всех броузерах , в виндоус на всех на ANDROID вообще ни в дном

Comment: На сколько я знаю редактировать все элементы формы напрямую нельзя. Обычно их используют скрытыми, а отрисовывают нужный дизайн стандартной версткой, после чего скриптами помечают нужные параметры input'ов и отправляют формой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обводка вокруг формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373270/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score -1):

У `select` :

```
select:active, select:focus{
  outline:none
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы