# как убрать outline и focuse у селект html

Tags: html, css

Как убрать фокус на десктопах при клике?

```
<select>
   <option>
        21
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: select{
    outline: none;
}

Comment: вот ссылка тут уже писалось даже сам автор приводит пример правда не на всех браузерах работает - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497013/border-%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-select-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-option

Comment: Вообще это плохая практика скрывать аутлайн полностью. Он не просто так был придуман.

Comment: @websnap, но смотрится он не очень, поэтому его и убирают в 99,99% случаев

Comment: @DaemonHK вряд ли я уйду с сайта из-за того, что какой-то элемент смотрится не очень. А с неудобного, раздражающего сайта я уйду однозначно.
И я не просто так написал "полностью". Его можно стилизовать по-своему или заменить, например, изменением цвета фона/текста при фокусе.
И это для вас как для верстальщика смотрится не очень. А вспомните времена, когда вы ничего об этом не знали. Сильно вам мешал аутлайн?

Comment: @websnap я уже не помню те времена, а "бордер" в виде свечения когда нажимаешь на кнопку или ссылку с изображением, как-то не очень

Comment: @DaemonHK а когда пользуешься исключительно клавиатурой, как-то не очень если не знаешь какой элемент в фокусе.
Сразу отвечаю на следующий вопрос: айтишники, геймеры и люди с ограниченными возможностями.

Comment: @websnap, в таком случае outline оставляют ленивые разрабы, которым лень оформлять элемент в фокусе, полагаясь на стандартную отрисовку браузера

Comment: @DaemonHK первое, что пришло в голову
ru.stackoverflow.com
https://css-tricks.com/
http://css.yoksel.ru/

Все еще думаете дело в лени? Или это все-таки вопрос здравого смысла?

Comment: @websnap, что-то я не вижу аутлайна у ссылок, изображений, инпутов...